# 3DS MAX CAT-RIG absolute animation layer from pose

Tags: animation, layer, 3dsmax

i am using the human cat rig and set up a absulute layer (this is the start pose) and a local layer (this is the animation between pose1 and pose2).

now i want to create a new absolute layer from this last frame. if i do this with "new absolute layer" -> "create pose by key frames" - button (i forgot the name). it will show my complete catrig in the color of the new layer, but as soon as i move in the timeline it get lost to 0% and i didnt get this up to 100% again ???

File: http://www.blackfreeze.de/sonstiges/14%20-%20Fin%20Scene%202.max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is quite simple :)

if you select the cat rig base you can save and load pose-files. so i had to save the pose with all mixed layers --> create a new absolute layer --> load the saved pose in there.

the reason why i want this: all keyframes after the new absolute layer have no effects on the other layers... so the will be safe :)